# Reemplazar valor NULL por numeros aleatorios SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, null

Estoy intentando reemplazar valores NULL por valores aleatorios
por ejemplo:

Tengo este codigo

```
SELECT bp.BPId, bp.BPTypeCode,  c.ClientId
FROM dbo.BusinessProcesses bp 
INNER JOIN dbo.BusinessProcessesTypes btp ON btp.BPTypeCode = bp.BPTypeCode
LEFT JOIN dbo.BPClientsRelations bpr ON bpr.BPId = bp.BPId
LEFT JOIN dbo.Clients c ON c.ClientId = bpr.ClientId
left JOIN dbo.OuterClients oc ON oc.OuterClientId = bpr.OuterClientId
WHERE bp.BPId IN ('648511803','648511923')
```

El cual me arroja este resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces lo que quiero es por ejemplo en el primer resultado es ves del Null me lo cambie por "123" y en el segundo resultado me cambie el null por "012"

Ya que lo que necesito es que al reemplazar el NULL no sean repetidos por eso no he usado ISNULL

Answer (score 5):

Puedes utilizar la expresión `ABS(CHECKSUM(NewId()))` para generar números que parecen aleatorios, pues se basan en la función `NewID()`.

OJO, que los números no necesariamente cumplen con las características de un buen generador de números pseudo-aleatorios (por ejemplo, podrían no tener una distribución normal), pero para la mayoría de los usos son suficientemente buenos.

Para generar números en un rango, utiliza la operación módulo (`%`), por ejemplo, para tener números entre 0 y 999, haz `modulo 1000`.

Finalmente, puedes usar la función `coalesce()` para sustituir los valores `null` por este número aletorio.

Poniendo todas las piezas juntas, podría lucir algo como:

```
SELECT bp.BPId, bp.BPTypeCode, coalesce(c.ClientId, ABS(CHECKSUM(NewId())) % 1000)
FROM dbo.BusinessProcesses bp 
INNER JOIN dbo.BusinessProcessesTypes btp ON btp.BPTypeCode = bp.BPTypeCode
LEFT JOIN dbo.BPClientsRelations bpr ON bpr.BPId = bp.BPId
LEFT JOIN dbo.Clients c ON c.ClientId = bpr.ClientId
left JOIN dbo.OuterClients oc ON oc.OuterClientId = bpr.OuterClientId
WHERE bp.BPId IN ('648511803','648511923')
```

Debiera arrojarte unos cuantos números entre 0 y 999.

Comment: Funciono Perfecto,

Comment: Me alegra ser de ayuda. Considera [marcar la respuesta como aceptada](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) y, si es de buena calidad, votar a su favor. Es la forma, en StackOverflow, de _agradecer_ a quien responde y de ayudar a navegantes futuros a identificar que la respuesta fue de ayuda.Si no sabes como aceptar una respuesta o como votar por ella, repite el [tour].